# How to remove old 32 bit registry after updating to 64 bit with install4j Add/Remove Feature?

Tags: java, registry, install4j

I have created a setup with install4j. Tho older version of my application  was 32 bit, now it is 64 bit. I want the older 32 bit versions to be updated to 64 bit.

The problem is, that when I execute the 64 bit setup on a system where already a 32 bit version is installed, there are two entries in the software registry "programs and features" afterwards. I think that the 64 bit setup does not find earlier installations that are 32 bit.

Is there any configuration in install4j or do I have to remove the entry manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 7.0.9, a 64-bit Windows installer will only detect previous 64-bit installations and a 32-bit Windows installer will only detect previous 32-bit installations.

Upgrades between 64-bit and 32-bit installers do not modify the registry of the other bitness. If you want to remove the 32-bit entry, you have to remove it with a call to `com.install4j.api.windows.WinRegistry`.

If you add a "Run script" action with the script:

```
import com.install4j.api.ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo;
ApplicationInfo[] infos = 
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById(context.getApplicationId());
if (infos.length > 0) {
    context.setInstallationDirectory(infos[0].getInstallationDirectory());
}

return true;
```

it will set the installation directory to a previous installation from the other bitness if no installation from the same bitness is found.

Comment: I would say it is a Bug, if the program Unique ID is the same.

Comment: I've added it to our issue tracker

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really love your products and support.